# How to open pop up Iframe lightbox on hover of any div

Tags: iframe, lightbox

Is there way to open  pop up Iframe lightbox on hover of any div. 
If any of you guys knows such examples can you please  post the link here

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), a jquery Lightbox alternative. Very simply you, can use an anchor element :

```
<a class="youtube cboxElement" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VOJyrQa_WR4?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To YouTube)</a>
```

Check the [Demos](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

If you want the popup to appear on hover, I think you will have to customize it on your own, by adding an event listener to the hoverable element :

```
$('#hoverableElement').hover( 
      function(){
           $('#hoverableElement').colorbox();
      } , 
      function(){
           $.colorbox.close();
      }  
);
```

where the element you want to trigger the popup will have the ID "hoverableElement".

Comment: Thank you for the reply , Its ok for click event   but i need on hover

Comment: If you want the popup to appear on hover, you will probably have to add a customized event listener (for hover events) on your element. I updated my post below.